# SORT ACCESS UNION QUERY SQL

Tags: ms-access

I applied a union query in this data

```
DRAW NO    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C8
DWG-1      D    D    C    C    A    A    B    B
DWG-2      B    B    A
```

Using this sql

```
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C1] AS Data FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C2] FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C3] FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C4] FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C5] FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C6] FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C7] FROM Query2
UNION SELECT [DRAW NO], [C8] FROM Query2;
```

And the results is like this

```
DRAW NO      DATA
DWG-1        A 
DWG-1        B
DWG-1        C
DWG-1        D
DWG-2        A
DWG-2        B
```

Is it possible to change the output to this kind of sorting?

```
DRAW NO      DATA
DWG-1        D 
DWG-1        C
DWG-1        A
DWG-1        B
DWG-2        B
DWG-2        A
```

**Edit** from the OP's comment:
I need to get the value of c1 first.. then c2.. if c2 has duplicates c3 should be the next value and so on.

Comment: What are the rules for *this kind of sorting*?

Comment: i need to get the value of c1 first.. then c2.. if c2 has duplicates c3 shoulde be the next value. and so on.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data this will work:

```
SELECT t.[DRAW NO], t.Data FROM (
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 1 AS col, [C1] AS Data FROM Query2 UNION  
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 2, [C2] FROM Query2 UNION
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 3, [C3] FROM Query2 UNION
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 4, [C4] FROM Query2 UNION
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 5, [C5] FROM Query2 UNION
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 6, [C6] FROM Query2 UNION
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 7, [C7] FROM Query2 UNION
  SELECT [DRAW NO], 8, [C8] FROM Query2
) AS t
WHERE  t.[Data] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.[DRAW NO], t.Data
ORDER BY t.[DRAW NO], MIN(t.col)
```

Results:

```
DRAW NO Data
DWG-1   D
DWG-1   C
DWG-1   A
DWG-1   B
DWG-2   B
DWG-2   A
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this did not work on my end, My data is not limited into ABCD.

Comment: You should mention this in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. This is noted. I will try to be more specific next time. Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: @raym Try to be specific this time also. Your requirement does not make since now that you edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain SQL for this:

```sql
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C1] AS Data FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C2] FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C3] FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C4] FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C5] FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C6] FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C7] FROM Query2
UNION 
SELECT [DRAW NO], [C8] FROM Query2

ORDER BY 
[Data]="D", [Data]="C", [Data]="A", [Data]="B";
```

Official documentation: [Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1F772EC0-CC73-474D-AB10-AD0A75541C6E)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this did not work on my end, My data is not limited into ABCD. I am working on a hundreds of data. Hope this could help understand my question.